# R: convert list of numbers from character to numeric

Tags: r, vector, character, numeric

I have a column in my dataframe where in every cell there are one or more numbers. If there are many numbers, they are seperated with a space. Furthermore, R considers them as a character vector. I'd really like to convert them to numeric (and if possible sum them up right away).
E.g. one of my cells might look like

```
6 310 21 20 64
```

I've tried

```
Reduce(sum,L)
```

and

```
as.numeric(L)
```

but I always get
Warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

Here, L is just a sample object I created to put one of my cells into.

Comment: Try `sum(as.numeric(strsplit("6 310 21 20 64",' ')[[1]]))`. You might have to modify the code a bit to apply it to all of your data. Post `dput` of your data if you need further help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?s=1|2.2808 Please give some data for L

Comment: Ok, in my example L<-c("6 310 21 20 64"). But this already works fine for me, thanks!

Comment: @etienne you could probably generalize this to `sapply(strsplit(str1,' '), function(x) sum(type.convert(x)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: thanks, I didn't know about `type.convert`

Comment: @etienne yo can use `as.numeric`. I've used `type.convert` so it will pick between `as.numeric` and `as.integer` automatically. You should post an answer anyway IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment, here is a solution using `sapply` :

```
sum(as.numeric(strsplit("6 310 21 20 64",' ')[[1]]))
```

which for the column of the dataframe will give something like this:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){sum(as.numeric(strsplit(str1,' ')[[x]]))})
# 421 421 421
```

which could be improved in `sapply(strsplit(str1,' '), function(x) sum(type.convert(x)))`, thanks to David Arenburg's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two more options which work correctly on a vector (it seems)

```
str1 <- c("6 310 21 20 64", "6 310 21 20 64","6 310 21 20 64")
rowSums(read.table(text = str1))
## [1] 421 421 421
```

Or using `data.table::fread`

```
rowSums(data.table::fread(paste(str1, collapse = "\n")))
# [1] 421 421 421
```

Or as mentioned in comments by @akrun, you can use `` Reduce(`+`,...) `` instead of `rowSums(...)` in both cases in order to avoid to `marix` conversion

Answer (score 4):

We can use `scan`

```
sum(scan(text=str1, what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE))
#[1] 421
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "6 310 21 20 64"
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg That is a nice option.  You could potentially post that as a solution

Comment: I think it's more general because your solution will give incorrect result for a vector (IMO), for example `str1 <- c("6 310 21 20 64", "6 310 21 20 64","6 310 21 20 64")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, only after I posted I realized that the OP has a dataframe.